# How do I a command alias with Windows

Tags: windows, shell

How can I do a command alias with Windows?
Example:

```
alias git="docker run -ti --rm -v $(pwd):/git -v $HOME/.ssh:/root/.ssh alpine/git"
```

Comment: Use a batch file?

Comment: No I can't. This command return git command from the container. Demo : https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/git/

Comment: For the CMD shell the only approach that works in general is a batch script. You can access all of the command-line arguments as `%*`, or individually as `%1` through `%9`.

Comment: If you only need an alias that works with a console read (i.e. from a console window hosted by conhost.exe), then you can use a console alias that's defined by doskey.exe. Such aliases are evaluated in the console before CMD reads a line of input. The console matches an alias at the start of the line, so an alias won't work on the right-hand side of the `&&`, `&`, `||`, and `|` operators, or in the body of an `if` or `for` statement. Obviously it also doesn't work when reading from a non-console file such as a batch file or when standard input is piped to CMD (e.g. some terminals and IDEs).